# Having a collection in class

Tags: c#, collections

There are several options when one class must have a container (collection) of some sort of objects and I was wondering what implementation I shall prefer.

Here follow the options I found:

```
public class AClass : IEnumerable<string>{
   private List<string> values = new List<string>()

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
      return GetEnumerator();
   }

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(){
      return values.GetEnumerator();
   }
}
```

**Pros**: AClass is not dependent on a concrete implementation of a collection (in this case List).

**Cons**: AClass doesn't have interface for Adding and removing elements

```
public class AClass : ICollection<string>{
   private List<string> values = new List<string>()

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
      return GetEnumerator();
   }

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(){
      return values.GetEnumerator();
   }

   //other ICollectionMembers
}
```

**Pros**: Same as IEnumerable plus it have interface for adding and removing elements

**Cons**: The ICollection interface define other methods that one rarely uses and it get's boring to implement those just for the sake of the interface. Also IEnumerable LINQ extensions takes care of some of those.

```
public class AClass : List<string>{

}
```

**Pros**: No need of implementing any method. Caller may call any method implemented by List

**Cons**: AClass is dependent on collection List and if it changes some of the caller code may need to be changed. Also AClass can't inherit any other class.

The question is: Which one shall I prefer to state that my class contains a collection supporting both Add and Remove operations? Or other suggestions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion is just define a generic List inside of your class and write additional `Add` and `Remove` methods like this and implement IEnumerable:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable
{
    private List<string> myList;

    public MyClass()
    {
        myList = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        if (item != null) myList.Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(string item)
    {
        if (myList.IndexOf(item) > 0) myList.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> MyList { get { return myList; } }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This is the best way if you don't want to implement your own collection.You don't need to implement an interface to `Add` and `Remove` methods.The additional methods like this fits your needs  I guess.

Comment: There is no need for method Add and Remove since you already have a Property to get the list. I like the ideia but I would make it return ICollection instead so it wouldn't have the same cons as my 3rd option.

Comment: you right,you can change it to ICollection, or IEnumerable is better.User can't add items to the list directly if you return IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is really an opinion based question which aren't specifically what SO is used for. However all implementations have different pro's and con's as you have listed, really the one you implement is the option that best fits the application use.

In my *personal opinion* I would go with option one and add the methods you need to interface with your inner collection. This is quite simple to implement and simple to use.

Something like.

```
public class AClass : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public AClass()
    {
        this.values = new List<string>();
    }

    private readonly List<string> values;

    public void Add(string inputString)
    {
        this.values.Add(inputString);
    }

    public void Remove(string inputString)
    {
        this.values.Remove(inputString);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return values.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now this has simple add \ remove features. Also note I used a `readonly` list as your list doesnt need to be rest after the constructor has been called.

**Update AS Per comment.**

Yes you do have convert from a List to the `AClass` other class (you would have to anyway). I have added an extra constructor and an implicit operator to cast from a List or an IEnumerable in the constructor.

```
public class AClass : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public static implicit operator AClass(List<string> collection)
    {
        return new AClass(collection);
    }

    public static implicit operator List<string>(AClass aClass)
    {
        return aClass.values;
    }

    public AClass()
    {
        this.values = new List<string>();
    }

    public AClass(IEnumerable<string> collection)
    {
        this.values = collection.ToList();
    }

    private readonly List<string> values;

    public void Add(string inputString)
    {
        this.values.Add(inputString);
    }

    public void Remove(string inputString)
    {
        this.values.Remove(inputString);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return values.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This could then be used as the following ways.:

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>();

AClass classA = new AClass(); //parameterless constructor
AClass classA1 = new AClass(listA); //simple constructor call with collection
AClass classA2 = (AClass)listA; //direct cast
List<string> listB = (List<string>)listA; //cast back to a list
```

Just an idea, again still a *personal opinion*.

Comment: The cons of this is that you would have to cast to AClass to Add and Remove (if you only knew it was an IEnumerable)

Comment: I have updated the response based on comment

Comment: I don't really like the Ideia of the casting operator (may be a personal taste), but was a good call to have the constructor.

Comment: I Prefer to expose the collection as a Property as Selman suggested, so this way I don't have to implement Add or Remove Methods.

Comment: Fair enough... Glad you found your answer..

Answer (score 1):

I liked the way you explained your thoughts.

You have found 3 perfectly goods ways of addressing some issues. You pros and cons make me feel you understand them correctly.

There is **no silver bullet to tackle all problems**. But you better have a software architect **toolbox** packed with **design patterns** and a sprinkle of common sense.

Next time you face a challenge use the best tool for the job!

Comment: And having a doubt like this almost after completing a college degree in computer engineering is quite bad I guess. But hey, all questions shall be made, I was also looking for consistency because whenever this problem occurred I think I faced it in different ways. Now I can have consistency and a way I like and feel reasonable to implement it.

Comment: It's not bat at all, quite the opposite. I usually use the generic List or inherit from it when i want to fill some known data in its constructor. But it's not always like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a small adaptation of what Selman suggested so his answer meets my expectations:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<string>
{
   private List<string> myList;

   public MyClass()
   {
       myList = new List<string>();
   }

   public ICollection<string> MyList { get { return myList; } }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
      return GetEnumerator();
   }

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(){
      return myList.GetEnumerator();
   }
}
```